# How to hide mounted partitions and devices from Unity Launcher via Command Line?

Tags: 12.04, mount, unity

I've checked and read similar questions, but most of the answers requires installing either **dconf-tools**, **CCSM** or **MyUnity**.

In Ubuntu 12.04, is there a way to hide mounted partitions or devices from the Unity Launcher *without the need to install* the aforementioned tools? Is this possible via terminal or command line?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195988/how-can-i-remove-launcher-drive-icons

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### From terminal:

- Hide mounted partition or devices:

  ```
    gconftool --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/devices_option  --type=int 0
  ```
- Show mounted partition or devices:

  ```
    gconftool --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/devices_option  --type=int 1
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You can install [Myunity](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/myunity/), wherein select the option from the Show Devices Menu from Launcher Menu Tab as here.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I was looking for a solution that doesn't need an additional app to be installed, if possible. My bad, I didn't mention myUnity in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to change the mount point. I noticed that it tends to only show devices mounted to `/media`.

In my case, I wanted to hide the internal drives that are mounted while showing my USB drives.