# How can I remove launcher drive icons?

Tags: unity, launcher

I can't disable showing drive's icons in Launcher bar. I have looked for that option both in CCSM (it used to be in Experimental tab) and in dconf-editor (desktop->unity) and it is missing.

[image: Drive icons in the launcher]

How can I remove launcher drive icons?

Comment: Doesen't sounds like you are using Unity. Wich Desktop do you have running?

Comment: Do you mean the shortcuts appear on the `Launcher`(the left-hand side vertical menu containing some applications)?

Comment: @Jobin ya like that only

Comment: @prophecy201..srry iam new to ubuntu.so if u ask like which desktop using i dnt knw.i just installed ubuntu 12.04.and the default one iam using

Comment: got answer from http://superuser.com/questions/555713/how-to-remove-shortcuts-of-drives-from-desktop-without-unmounting-it-in-ubuntu/556415?noredirect=1#556415

Answer (score 47):

**(For Ubuntu 12.10 or above)**

You are right that there used to be a setting in CCSM to configure the behaviour of mounts appearing in the launcher but that option has been removed in 12.10 at the moment. I can't confirm whether it will be added back again before it is released to the public. See [bug report #1053704.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1053704)

Currently, you only have two options: Either to show the mount drives on the launcher or to blacklist it from the launcher. You can't configure the setting depending on whether they are actually mounted or not.

So, if you want to remove it from the launcher, the only option you have is to blacklist it from the launcher.

Blacklisting it from the launcher is actually very simple. Right-click on the mount and select *Unlock from Launcher*.

[image: Remove mount from launcher]

Do remember that blacklisting it from launcher means you will never see it again in the future even if you mount it unless you reset the settings.

---

You can also blacklist the mounts using `dconf-editor` or `gsettings` command but that requires you know the UUIDs of the mounts.

If you are using `dconf-editor`, scroll down to `com` → `canonical` → `Unity` → `devices` and enter the UUID of the mount in `blacklist`.

[image: Dconf-editor]

If you want to use `gsettings`, you can use a command of this format:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist "['UUID of your mount']"
```

Just use the UUID of your mount inside the square bracket and the single quote marks.

If you are not sure of the UUID of your mount, you can use this command:

```
sudo blkid -o list
```

It will display the partition number, their label (if any) with their UUID.

---

Now, if you want to reset the settings, run this command in a terminal:

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist
```

*Works with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.*

Comment: What about usb drives, phones, cameras ? They're constantly keeps showing in the launcher every time I connect them. I don't need this?

Comment: Blacklisting might be OK for permanently attached storage, but USB drives etc still appear. I want as permanent solution to this problem for all types of drive and for installed programs would be nice too.

Comment: @AndrewHeath is correct, this doesn't work on USB storage drives and devices, every time they are plugged in, all the partitions and volumes icons are still automatically displayed on the launcher.

Comment: Also doesn't work on CDs that are inserted.  This is making me crazy!

Comment: I've created a launchpad issue for this -- please vote it up.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/launcher/+bug/1103593

Comment: One more detail. When you do 'Unlock from Launcher' (which does work) it is actually 'UUID-Label' in dconf rather than just 'UUID'. I'm not sure how it was in 12.10, but this is now the case for 13.04.

Answer (score 21):

**(For Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04)**

1. Install [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/) if you haven't already.
2. Run *CompizConfig Settings Manager* and navigate to the Unity plugin.
3. In the *Experimental Tab*, change the *Show Devices* combobox to *Never*.

   [image]

Comment: The option is missing from ccsm in Ubuntu 12.10. It's not in Ubuntu Tweak 0.8.2 either.

Comment: Sweet! That was very useful

Comment: Does this still work in 16.10?

Answer (score 7):

Install `MyUnity` by using `sudo apt-get install myunity`, then run `MyUnity` from dash and in the `Launcher` section, select `Never` from `Show Devices` Drop Down menu, That's it!

Comment: I actually followed the answer from Jakob's link, but I guess this would work as well.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 seem to not have myunity in common repos, where will i find it?

Comment: This is the easy way

Answer (score 6):

Open `dconf-editor`: Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `dconf-editor` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In `dconf-editor` goto: `com` ➤ `canonical` ➤ `unity` ➤ `devices`.

You will see blacklist with key ['UUID-Label']. Add your UUID and devices-Label in it.

Comment: The following answer goes more into detail: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195988/how-to-remove-launcher-drive-icons

Answer (score 3):

To completely disable drive icons in the Launcher for *all* current drives and partitions, simply run the following command:

```
gconftool --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/devices_option  --type=int 0
```

Note that this does not immediately remove any icons currently displayed in the Launcher; it simply prevents icons from appearing in the first place. Thus, any drive icons that appeared before executing this command will never re-appear once they are removed one time. Removal of an icon can be achieved, for example, by an unlock (via the icon's right-click menu) or restart of Ubuntu.

To re-enable drive icons, run the same command with a `1` instead of a `0` at the end.

This command has worked for me in both 12.04 and 14.04. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to prevent icons from appearing when I plug in external hard drives or flash drives via USB. Nonetheless, it does stop icons for my all of my primary hard drive's partitions from appearing.

I got the command from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/159069/236970) to a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gconf-editor`.
2. Navigate to `/apps/nautilus/desktop`.
3. Deselect `volumes_visible`.

<sup>([source](https://superuser.com/questions/555713/how-to-remove-shortcuts-of-drives-from-desktop-without-unmounting-it-in-ubuntu))</sup>

Comment: No such command in a clean Ubuntu 23.10 installation, Wikipedia says it’s discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

To turn off showing mounts in the Ubuntu 22.04, I used the solution described [here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/11/hide-mounted-drives-left-dock-ubuntu-19-10/). It is as running following command in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false
```

Answer (score 0):

IT isn't working for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. cant see apps/nautilus/desktop folder there. For that you need to install this

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Than follow attached images Below

1. [Search for Gnomre-Tweaks in Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4kFm.png)
2. [Than do this from Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UK8L.png)