# Can't see my flash drive on the Launcher

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I unlocked my 4GB flash drive from the Launcher, but can't I figure out how to get it back on. I can't seem to find it anywhere. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use your `Gparted`.If its already installed , just type gparted in your Unity dash. If not installed type as

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

and then launch it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same on Ubuntu 14.04. Thou I don't know the version of your system, for me the solution found in this thread worked perfectly:

[How can I remove launcher drive icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195988/how-can-i-remove-launcher-drive-icons)

Just type on a terminal:

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist
```