# CD/DVD launcher will not show up

Tags: unity, launcher, cd-drive

I accidentally clicked the Unlock from Launcher instead of eject. Now the launcher doesn't show up at all when a CD/DVD is inserted so I cannot lock it back to the launcher.

I don't want to create a launcher that is always visible, I only want to see the icon when a CD/DVD is inserted.

I need some help to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

It will only blacklist per cd.
So if you insert another cd/dvd it will show up again.

To remove the blacklisting see this answer:

[How can I remove launcher drive icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195988/how-to-remove-launcher-drive-icons)

The section on dconf-edtor is the easiets.
Just set the blacklist on the device to ''