# Unity Launcher "Stuck" icons

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I'm trying to make my ubuntu clean and tidy, and there is a few launchers on the unity-bar i would love to get rid of.
For example, I love the feature with the `desktop-switcher`. But, I am only using my keyboard for that function, and the icon on the unity-bar is annoying me (since i am never using it).
I can't just put it in the trash, it's stuck on the bar.
I've tried to go to the appearance settings, and ticked away the checkbox for the desktop-switcher. The thing is, *it disables the whole* feature, and that's annoying.

Another example; Mounted hard-drives and USB-pens? Why do they have to appear on the bar as well as other things?
And the "Show Desktop" Icon?

Those icons are taking too much space on the bar, and i want them gone,

If you have any smart ideas on how i could customize Unity for my purposes, I would love to hear from you.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools)[image: Install dconf], if you don't have it already installed.

Then open **dconf-editor** (search for it in the Dash) and browse to **com** → **canonical** → **unity** → **launcher**, and edit the **favorites** field by removing the `, 'unity://expo-icon'` string:

[image: dconf-editor]

After this, your **Workspace Switcher** icon will disappear from the launcher.

For mounted hard-drives and USB-pens, just right click on their icons and select **Unlock from Launcher**:

[image: unlock from launcher]

See also:

- [How can I remove launcher drive icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195988/how-to-remove-launcher-drive-icons)