# How to get rid of disk icons in Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, filesystem, icons

I have got here an installation of Unity and I am annoyed with the 3 disk icons in the Launcher right below the workspace switcher. Is there a way to prevent these icons from showing?

[image]

Those 3 icons right above the trash.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot? I have no idea what icons you are referring to.

Comment: Well? How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Dash icon, it seems it's Ubuntu 12.04.
Kindly follow these instructions:

1. Install compizconfig-settings-manager if you haven't already.

   `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Run *CompizConfig Settings Manager* and navigate to the Unity plugin.
3. In the *Experimental Tab*, change the *Show Devices* combobox to *Never*.

   [image]

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/62015/163331

Comment: But it's not locked to the launcher... When I right click the options are: lock to launcher, open, format, unmount

Comment: That's looks like Ubuntu 12.04, follow these instructions: http://askubuntu.com/a/62015/163331