# How to permanently unlock partitions from launcher in 16.04

Tags: command-line, launcher, devices, gsettings, unlock

I tried to unlock partitions from the launcher, but they keeps reappearing after every reboot. Is there any good way to permanently remove partitions from the launcher?

This is happening only on Ubuntu 16.04

[image]

Comment: How about automatically mounting them on startup? [Link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup-in-ubuntu-12-04). After mounting they dont show up anymore.

Comment: When you unlock them from the launcher, are they actually blacklisted?  See the answer here for instructions on how to check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195988/how-can-i-remove-launcher-drive-icons

Comment: Hi @Severus Tux. Not sure the issue is 16.04 specific. It occurs to me I've heard of it before. Anyway, posted a workaround. Please mention if you manage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the solution below is not a *fix* to what *seems* to be a minor bug, you can use it as a workaround to automatically blacklist devices on startup (log in).

#### The solution

...is a small script that remembers your blacklisted items on log in. It runs with two arguments: `get` and `set`. The first is to read the current blacklisted items, the second will (re-) set the list to the last read version.

#### In practice

- Remove the devices from the Unity Launcher like you are used to.
- Run the command `/path/to/remember_blacklist.sh get`
  This will make a snapshot of the currently blacklisted devices.

Now the next time you log in or restart, the blacklisted devices are automatically removed. Of course you can add the command to a shortcut.

#### How to use / set up

- Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `remember_blacklist.sh`

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/bash

  arg=$1
  blacklist=~/.currblacklist
  key="com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist"

  if [ "$arg" == "get" ]
  then
   printf "$(gsettings get $key)" > $blacklist
  elif [ "$arg" == "set" ]
  then
    if [ "$(cat $blacklist)" == "@as" ]
    then 
      gsettings set $key []
    else
      gsettings set $key "$(cat $blacklist)"
    fi
  fi
  ```
- *make it executable* (!)
- Add the following to Startup Applications Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command

  ```
  /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && /path/to/remember_blacklist.sh set"
  ```
- Remove the devices from the launcher as usual
- To remember, run: `/path/to/remember_blacklist.sh get`

#### Explanation

If you remove a device from the launcher, it is *blacklisted*. You can read the current list of blacklisted devices with the command:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist
```

This will output something like

```
['0A444ED409660B91-intern_1', '2899FAA548C61099-intern_2']
```

What the script does is:

- when run with the argument `get`: it reads the current blacklist and saves the output in a hidden file: `~/.currblacklist`
- when run with the argument `set`: it reads the content of the file `~/.currblacklist` and sets the blaclist with the command:

  ```
  gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist <content_of_the_file>
  ```

Comment: Brilliant!!, do you mind telling me what is `@as` (12th line in your script). Thanks :-)

Comment: @SeverusTux That's a secret code :), no seriously, if there are no items blacklisted, the command returns `@as`. This cannot be used to *set* an empty list however, then we need to use `[]`.

Comment: @SeverusTux you know that always makes me happy :)

Comment: This scripts on a first attempt, but after restarting my session a second time all drives are back. Could there something wrong with my script? Or is this method no longer viable on newer Ubuntu versions?